# Is there a way to use Scala sequences with performance comparable to Java arrays?

Tags: arrays, scala, sequence

I have a Scala application that needs to move around large blocks of binary (bytes) data. Following good practice, I prefer to keep data as immutable sequences rather than mutable arrays. Parts of the application are running much slower than expected and I've traced the problem to slow operations performed upon sequences such as using slice to access portions of the data.

For example, consider the following code that copies data to an output stream via an intermediate buffer. I have one version that uses Arrays and another that uses various implementations of Seq:

```scala
package app.continuity

import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, OutputStream}
import scala.collection.immutable.ArraySeq
import scala.util.Random

object SequenceTest extends App {
  val data: Array[Byte] = new Random().nextBytes(1000000)
  val dataAsSeq = data.toIndexedSeq
  val dataAsVector = Vector(data: _*)
  val dataAsArraySeq = ArraySeq(data: _*)
  val output = new ByteArrayOutputStream(10000000)
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](4096)

  def write1(data: Array[Byte], output: OutputStream): Unit = {
    var position: Int = 0
    while(position < data.length) {
      val writeSize = Math.min(data.length - position, buffer.length)
      System.arraycopy(data, position, buffer, 0, writeSize)
      output.write(buffer, 0, writeSize)
      position += writeSize
    }
  }

  def write2(data: Seq[Byte], output: OutputStream): Unit = {
    var position: Int = 0
    while (position < data.length) {
      val writeSize = Math.min(data.length - position, buffer.length)
      data.slice(position, writeSize).copyToArray(buffer, 0, writeSize)
      output.write(buffer, 0, writeSize)
      position += writeSize
    }
  }

  def showTime(description: String, last: Long): Long = {
    val next = System.nanoTime()
    val delta = (next - last) / 1000
    println(s"$description: $delta uSec")
    next
  }

  var time = System.nanoTime()
  write1(data, output)
  time = showTime("Array via arraycopy", time)
  write2(dataAsSeq, output)
  time = showTime("Seq via toIndexSeq", time)
  write2(dataAsVector, output)
  time = showTime("Seq via Vector", time)
  write2(dataAsArraySeq, output)
  time = showTime("Seq via ArraySeq", time)
}
```

Obviously in the case of the array, I could have just written the full array directly to the stream but the actual code is more complicated and needs intermediate buffers.

Running this code produces the following results:

```
Array via arraycopy: 301 uSec
Seq via toIndexSeq: 2398 uSec
Seq via Vector: 2586 uSec
Seq via ArraySeq: 643 uSec
```

Even though ArraySeq is supposedly just wrapping an array, it takes twice as long to access the data. I suspect the problem, in this case, is using slice to access portions of the source data, but I don't see anything like System.arraycopy that indexes into the source data for sequences. I'm using Scala 2.13 and Java 17. I tried the same code in Scala 3 which has IArray but it gives similar results as it still requires slice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you doing an explicit copy in `write2` rather than using the `slice` directly? Using `sliding(writeSize)` rather than a `while` loop would probably help as well.

Comment: Can you repeat those tests a bunch of times and see what happens? I tried to run your code a few times and I got a lot of variance. Ideally, for microbenchmarking you are probably better off using JMH so that you don't have to re-invent the (benchmarking) wheel. That should give you some reliable numbers to use for your comparison.

Comment: Rather than going low level, try to go even higher level using things like **fs2** or **AkkaStreams** to manage I/O in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

My [results](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PDpddIYfQtGxe6c7C9am3Q) are rather different from yours:

```
Array: 1795 uSec
Seq: 705 uSec
Iseq: 758 uSec
Aseq: 634 uSec
NOTHING: 729 uSec
```

(This is from running locally on my laptop, scastie is slower, but same relative scale).

As you can see, not only the "arraycopy" variant is *the slowest of all*, but also the last experiment I added, *doing absolutely nothing* is slower than some of the actual implementations, which demonstrates, that the operation you are testing is actually so fast, that the time it takes to perform is negligible compared to the function invocation.

I also added a more idiomatic scala implementation (denoted as "GROUPED" below), which happens to be consistently faster than the one you have, albeit marginally:

```
def grouped(d: Seq[Byte], out: OutputStream) = {
   d.iterator.grouped(4096).map(_.toArray).map(out.write)
   out.close()
}
```

```
Array: 2237 uSec
Seq: 905 uSec
Iseq: 747 uSec
Aseq: 640 uSec
GROUPED: 589 uSec
NOTHING: 582 uSec
```

Comment: Following the suggestion of @stefanobaghino , I rewrote the benchmark tests to use the Java Microbenchmark Harness (JMH). There is a GitHub project that captures the revised version: https://github.com/jlgula/Benchmark. The results, shown in the README, still show significantly slower performance writing from sequences compared to writing from arrays. To answer Tim, I tried using sliding from a sequence and the results were not good. If the source is known to be an array, then no copy is needed but the question was about writing sequences to an OutputStream.